# Overlapping classifications

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to create classifications based on date that are overlapped between each other.

Taking "Sample - EU SuperStore" as a reference, I want to do the the following:

- Show measures as rows, for example **Sum of Profit** and **sum of Sales**
- Create two columns: 2016 and Q1 2016.

Output Example:

```
+-------------+---------+---------+
|  Measures   |  2016   | Q1 2016 |
+-------------+---------+---------+
| sum(Profit) | 49,544  | 3,811   |
| sum(Sales)  | 484,247 | 74,448  |
+-------------+---------+---------+
```

Is there a way to achieve this without changing the underlying data model?

I've tried using parameters but at the moment of putting to parameters together they are consider as the same column with different "hierarchies". See image below (Parameters are called 1 and 2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your periods of interest only overlap because one of them is a total of some of the others, you may be able to just use turn on the totals and sub totals of interest from the menu.

Otherwise, you can define calculated fields that select your values of interest for some records, and null for other records. Some people call those conditional fields or conditional calculations. Since aggregation functions like SUM(), MAX() ignore null values, you can then use those fields as measures to get the effect you want.

For instance, if you create a calculated field called **[Sales During Promotion]** as

```
If [Date] >= #2/15/2020# and [Date] <= #3/15/2020# then [Sales] end
```

Then SUM([Sales During Promotion]) will be the sum of all sales that fell within the specified period.

The last trick to understand the calculated field above is to know that the default behavior if there is no else branch specified is to return null.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  The desire output are columns that have to coexist between each other without being totals, because the number of columns that are overlapped could be multiple.

Comment: In that case, you can create a “conditional” calculated field as above for each measure of Interest, and use Measure Names and Measure Values to build your view.